# Invalid Column Name using Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework

Using the ASP.NET Identity Model with some custom tables, today I started getting "Invalid Column Name 'AspNetUser_Id'" when querying table PortalActivityRole that does not relationships or fields associated to the AspNetUser table. Does anyone have any recommendations in addition to the threads on overflow which I have already read?

[image: PortalActivityRole]

This is "db first" and my mappings for PortalActivityrole are:

```
public class PortalActivityRoleMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<PortalActivityRole>
{
    public PortalActivityRoleMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => new { t.ActivityId, t.RoleId });

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.ActivityId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        this.Property(t => t.RoleId)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(128);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("PortalActivityRole");
        this.Property(t => t.ActivityId).HasColumnName("ActivityId");
        this.Property(t => t.RoleId).HasColumnName("RoleId");
        this.Property(t => t.DateCreated).HasColumnName("DateCreated");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.AspNetRole)
            .WithMany(t => t.PortalActivityRoles)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.RoleId);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.PortalActivity)
            .WithMany(t => t.PortalActivityRoles)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ActivityId);

    }
}
```

PortalActivityRole class is:

```
public partial class PortalActivityRole
{
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateCreated { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetRole AspNetRole { get; set; }
    public virtual PortalActivity PortalActivity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what is your EF query ?

Comment: You need to include the *actually* exception (message and type) otherwise it's a pretty pointless quesiton.

Comment: I was making changes to the code manually based on what was regenerated from EF Power Tools and fixed the issue above by including all of the regenerated code. As a rule of thumb when using "DB First" and the EF Power Tools, and introducing new changes to the model, when things start breaking it is better to include all of the generated code before manually making changes to it.